# Calling Ada from C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, ada

I am trying to create a program that is completely hosted in Eclipse, starts in C++, and calls Ada.  I have GNATBench loaded, and can run Ada programs without a problem.  What I cannot do is have a C++ project call an Ada project.

After hunting around, I found and executed the code shown below using a make file.

http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/book.html

I also found a post stating that my goal has been done.

http://blogs.windriver.com/parkinson/2009/10/yesterday-adacore-announced-the-release-of-gnatbench-231-its-ada-integrated-development-environment-eclipse-plugin-which.html

What else do I need to include to have C++ in Eclipse call Ada in Eclipse?

---

USING MAKE FILE:

```
$ c++ -c test.cc
$ gnatgcc -c test_subr
$ gnatbind -n test_subr
$ gnatgcc -c b~test_subr
$ gnatlink -o main test.o test_subr.ali --link=c++
$ ./main
```

CPP Code:

```
//main.cc

#include extern "C" void adainit(void);    
#include extern "C" void adafinal(void);
#include extern "C" void ada_subroutine(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   puts("C++ main");
   adainit();

   ada_subroutine();

   adafinal();
   puts("C++ done");

   return 0;
}
```

Ada Code:

```
package Test_Subr is
    procedure Ada_Subroutine;
    pragma export(CPP, Ada_Subroutine);
end Test_Subr;

with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Test_Subr is

    procedure Ada_Subroutine is
    begin
        put("IN ADA");
    end Ada_Subroutine;

end Test_Subr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the External_Name parameter of the Export pragma? (IIRC, C++ linkages can get quite mangled.)

```
pragma Export
( Convention    => CPP,
  Entity        => Ada_Subroutine,
  External_Name => "Ada_Subroutine "
);
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to set up the IDE preferences?  I can compile the Ada, but the C++ errors out (saying that adainit, ada_subroutine, and adafinal cannot be found).   Is this the only modification to the code I need to make?

Comment: Possibly; you see the `External_Name` parameter of the pragma overrides the default 'label' given to it in the object-file that is created; when the linker takes the object-file generated by C++ it needs the name specified to match with the one in the other object-file.

If not, I notice that the #import extern says C; while the Ada export says CPP, you could try making them both C.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know Eclipse; but, how would you get a C++ project in Eclipse to call up another C++ project? or one written in C?

You might be able to get Eclipse to [build the Ada as a library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Creating-a-Stand_002dalone-Library-to-be-used-in-a-non_002dAda-context.html#Creating-a-Stand_002dalone-Library-to-be-used-in-a-non_002dAda-context) and invoke that from the C++?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you need to use `extern C` on the C++ side and `pragma exprort (C, ..` on the Ada side to get both linkages (parameter passing schemes) the same. However, if you are using gcc for both Ada and C++ then you could use `pragma export (CPP` instead.

There is one more nit you have to be aware of. If your "main" (the program's entry point) [is not written in Ada](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Binding-with-Non_002dAda-Main-Programs.html#Binding-with-Non_002dAda-Main-Programs), then you will need to manually invoke Ada's elaboration process (via the routine `adainit()`) once before calling anything. Likewise you should in most cases call `adafinal()` before exiting your program.