# Can you export Ada generic functions to C++?

Tags: c++, c, ada

I have seen numerous places that communication between Ada/C/C++ is possible using export/import keywords. What about if the Ada function is a generic; is this even possible?

My problem is that I need to reuse some legacy code and we have numerous generic Ada functions. The new layer coming will be written in C++ and I am hoping to be able to export these existing Ada generic functions to a C++ wrapper. (Actually, if the functions aren't global I will need another layer but nevermind that right now.)

If it is NOT possible I will just need to create new individual Ada functions specific to the different types which in turn call the generic. Any thoughts about this approach?

I am definitely a noob with Ada programming so excuse my ignorance. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a small Ada package whose specification contains the [exported](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-1.html) subprograms and whose body instantiates those subprograms using the types available in [*§B.3 Interfacing with C and C++*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-3.html). Don't neglect to call `adainit()` and `adafinal()` on the C side. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10180040/230513).

Comment: I was thinking this is what I was going to have to do. I was just hoping the language allowed for it rather than having to write n number of functions for each generic. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem isn't [just] Ada in this case, but C++ there's no way to say "hey, compiler, this is a package/unit/module/template," is there?  It would be interesting to see if there was a way to export whole packages, but that would involve other languages a) demanding those packages, and b) actually having the facilities for packages.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar w/ Ada, but you should be able to call exported functions (assuming the Ada compiler does nothing too perverse). You should try dumping the Ada object file (the result of compilation) to inspect the function names.

Comment: The problem is with Ada's generic (equivalent of C++ template).

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant at all. He asked about mixed language programming. The fact he needs to invoke an object-oriented construct from c code is irrelevant. To invoke the exported funtion, he should only need access to the funtion signature

Comment: It’s very relevant; you can’t call a C++ template function from C++ or C, you can only call an instantiated template function. In the same way, you can’t call a generic subprogram; you have to instantiate it first, and then call the instantiation.

Comment: @SimonWright, slight vocabulary problem. It isn't "template function" but "function template" (i.e. template for generating function, a function template isn't a function): There was a time when template function was used for what is now called instantiation of a function template (which is indeed a function), but that was error prone.

Comment: @user590028, you miss the fact that the whole goal of generics or templates is to allow their use with several types (i.e. they have several signatures, often an open set of signatures).

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and time everyone. trashgod's suggestion above i think is what I have to do.